# How to make Bow Tie shape with for - while loops in C

Tags: c

Actually I did the easy part, but couldn't get more. I am a new Comp Eng student and we're trying to learn Loops. Our professor gave us this work to learn something. I did first part easily from last lesson. But I dont know how to lead it further.

[I need to reflect this and get a full Bow Tie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9FzH.png)

Here it is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(); {

    int sayi;

    printf("Sayiyi gir > ");
    scanf("%d",&sayi);

    for (int i = 0; i < sayi; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("*\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = sayi; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("*\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no 'main' function:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  It is easier for people to help you if they can easily run your code.  Providing complete code makes that simple.

Comment: Thanks for tip, added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like:

```
for (i = 0; i <= sayi; i++) {
    // Prints left part of the tie in row
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      printf("*\t");
    }
    // Prints the spaces between tie edges
    for (j = 0; j < sayi - i; j++) {
        printf("\t\t");
    }
    // Prints right part of the tie in row
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      printf("*\t");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Repeat similar but reverse for lower part of the tie.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I am trying to learn!